# Postgresql: Split string by comma and merge

Tags: sql, postgresql, split

Is there a way to split a string and regroup the values like below in Postgresql.

```
input_column
abc.1, xyz.1, abc.2, abc.3 xyz.3


result_column
abc{1,2,3}, xyz{1,3}
```

Comment: Should `abc.3 xyz.3` be `abc.3, xyz.3` (comma vs. space)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first split the items into rows and the aggregate back:

```
select code, array_agg(value) as values
from (
  select split_part(item, '.', 1) as code, 
         split_part(item, '.', 2) as value 
  from the_table t
    cross join regexp_split_to_table(t.input_column, '\s*,\s*') as x(item)
) t    
group by code
order by code
```

I used `regexp_split_to_table()` to generate the rows rather than `string_to_array()` and `unnest()` so deal with the whitespace after the comma. With a combination of `unnest()` and `string_to_array()` this would require an additional `trim()` that makes the inner query a bit harder to read.

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=58d73a07fc722f8ccfb8c50d5384914f)